Import exact React components from a directory
I am making an NextJS app with TS and is trying to make a documentation app. Each documentation is represented as a component (i.e. Content1.tsx, Content2.ts, etc) using client side rendering (CSR). On the main page, I am trying to display the component that is selected by the user through buttons by string value like so,
import Part1 from './contents/Part1'
import Part2 from './contents/Part2'
import Part3 from './contents/Part3'

const contentsMap: Record<string, JSX.Element> = {
  Part1: <Part1 />,
  Part2: <Part2 />,
  Part3: <Part3 />,
};

so that I can later set the states like so
const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string>("Part1");
const [content, setContent] = useState<JSX.Element>(contentsMap[selected]);

My question lies on how to automate this. How do I make it so that every .tsx components inside the ./contents directory is automatically imported and added to the Map so that there is no need for manual addition (i.e. for Part4) on CSR?

I'd prefer if I could leave this as a comment but I don't have the reputation required yet.
I'm not ultra familiar with Next.js but I believe you should be able to dynamically import the modules.
Except if you generate this file, I don't think there is any other way of automating this with static imports.
For dynamic imports see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import
React has an api for lazy loading components with dynamic import: https://react.dev/reference/react/lazy
There must be something similar to this in next.js if you look at the docs.
